# Reorder image gallery

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, yui, yahoo

I have an unordered list of image thumbnails. Each thumbnail links to the full size image.
I use the YUI3 library to allow drag & drop reordering of the thumbnail images (just the out-of-the-box example code).

The problem is the link to the fullsize image: it is not draggable. Only the small portions underneath the thumbnail (with title and value) are draggable.

```
<ul>
<li class="imgcontainer">
    <div>
        <a href="/image.jpg">
        <img src="thumbnail.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="left">Title</div>
    <div class="right">$2.00</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</li>
<!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

What is the best way to allow users to reorder the images in such an image gallery?
Add a drag handle icons to a corner of the list items?
Create a "reorder mode" in which the link anchors are removed, leaving only draggable images?
Or can it be set up so that the links still can be dragged?

Comment: show your code, so we can see for example, what you are attaching the events to

Comment: I attach the drag event to the list item. So the whole container is draggable - except the link to the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the anchor tag is not a valid drag handle per default. You can change this by using removeInvalid('a') on your drag instance.

```
var dd1 = new Y.DD.Drag({
    node: '#drag1'
});

dd1.removeInvalid('a');
```

Another option would be to remove the anchor tag

```
<div class="linked-image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/50/50" border="0" alt="" />
</div>
```

and add a click listener to the image.

```
Y.on('click', function () {
    alert('go to url');
}, '.linked-image');
```

Both approaches are demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/xGQne/

Note that the click event fires after the drag is completed in both cases. You will need to differentiate between clicks and drags to make this work smoothly.